# SSIS package with multiple constraints

Tags: ssis

Shown below is part of an SSIS package that runs daily. My objective is to execute the task **'Get Greaterthan500 Count on  Mondays**' only on Mondays. However, I want the **'Send Mail Task**' to be executed on all days. 
This is not working. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Brad's answer works because both nodes need to reach Send Mail in order for Send mail to work in your layout. It can never happen because your decision is binary (one way or the other) and both paths cannot reach Send Mail.

Answer (score 2):

Put the fist 2 in a sequence container.

Then have the send mail outside the sequence container and the send email will always be hit